# Does restarting celery cause duplicate tasks?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, django-celery

I have an email task in celery that has an eta of 10 days from now(). However, I'm finding that some people are getting 5-6 duplicate emails at a time. I've come across this problem before with BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS set too low. Now I have this in my settings file:

```
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 2592000} #30 days
```

So that shouldn't be a problem any more. I'm just wondering if there is anything else that can cause it. i.e. restarting celery. Celery gets restarted every time I deploy new code and that can happen 5 or more times a week so it's the only thing I can think of.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Which broker are you using and can you see the tasks queued?

Comment: @AndrewS I'm using redis. Yes I can see the tasks queued. The list is very long so it's difficult to see if there are any issues by just looking.

Answer (score 3):

Task duplicating is possible if worker/beat processes had not stopped correctly. How do you restart celery workers/beat? Check server for zombie celery worker and beat processes. Try to stop all celery processes, check no processes of celery exist and start it again. After all check that `ps ax | grep celery` shows fresh workers and only one beat.

Comment: I'm running celery under supervisord. The command I use is supervisorctl restart celery. Thanks, I'll have a look at that later.

Comment: So I've just checked. There is only one process running. Also the supervisord startup script is this: `/envs/flavourly/bin/python /envs/flavourly/bin/celery --app=flavourly.celery:app worker -P gevent --concurrency=10 --loglevel=INFO`

Answer (score 2):

Tasks won't restart in case of incorrect worker stop if you set `CELERY_ACKS_LATE = False`. In this case the task marked as acknowledged immediately after consuming. See [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#faq-acks-late-vs-retry).

Also make sure that your tasks have no `retry` enabled. If any exception happens inside task - they might retry with the same input arguments.

Another possible case - your tasks are written wrong and each run selects the same recipients set.